# не создается проект в Visual studio C#

Tags: visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]создаю проект, выбираю шаблон консольное приложение (майкрософт), выбираю расположение и имя, платформу. нажимаю создать и выходит это..
проектов ноль[[image: не могу запустить и нет файла для кода][1]]

Comment: .csproj в директории проекта есть?